# Split data into multiple worksheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, worksheet

Since I am going to create a number of dataframes I know won't fit inside just a single google worksheet (because of the limitation of columns) I want to split the data into multiple worksheets. I'm using `set_with_dataframe()` and defining which worksheet the dataframes is going to get imported to, so my first thought was to create and define several worksheets and then use the same method - the problem is just that I don't know how to "split" the data when there's no more columns in the first worksheet (and then the second, and the third and so on...)

I'm quite new at working with Python and I have been stuck with this for days so any kind of help would be appreciated.

My code looks like this:

```
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import get_as_dataframe, set_with_dataframe
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import traceback
import os

class DataScraper():

    def __init__(self, sheets):

        self.data_worksheet = sheets.data_worksheet
        self.total_urls = 0
        self.urls = self.getAllUrls(sheets.url_worksheet)

    def getAllUrls(self, urlWorkSheet):
        urls = urlWorkSheet.get_all_values()
        finalUrls = []
        for r in urls:
            # Get all urls 
            modifiedUrls = [d for d in r[:14] if "https://" in d]
            

            if len(modifiedUrls) != 0:
                self.total_urls += len(modifiedUrls)
                finalUrls.append(modifiedUrls)
        return finalUrls
    
    
    def StartScrape(self):
        current_column_count = 1
        last_data_frame_max_width = 0
        
        current_element = 0

        for urlRow in self.urls:
            current_row_count = 1

            for url in urlRow:
                current_element += 1
                error = False

                page = requests.get(url)
                soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
                try:
                    page = requests.get(url)
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

                    labels = [] 
                    results = []

                    tbl = soup.find('table')
                    for tr in tbl.findAll('tr'):
                        headers = [th.text.strip()  for th in tr.findAll('th')]
                        data = [td.text.strip() for td in tr.findAll('td')]
                        labels.append(headers)
                        results.append(data)

                    final_results = []

                    for final_labels, final_data in zip(labels, results):
                        final_results.append({'Labels': final_labels, 'Data': final_data})
                    df = pd.DataFrame(final_results)

                    df['Labels'] = df['Labels'].str[0]
                    df['Data'] = df['Data'].str[0]

                    indexNames = df[df['Labels'] == 'Links'].index
                    df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)

                    set_with_dataframe(self.data_worksheet, df, col=current_column_count, row=current_row_count, include_column_header=False)

                    current_row_count += df.shape[0]+2
                    if df.shape[1] > last_data_frame_max_width:
                        last_data_frame_max_width = df.shape[1]

                except Exception:
                    error = True

                finally:
                    print(f"Processed page {current_element}/{self.total_urls} with status: {'success' if not error else 'error'}")

            current_column_count += last_data_frame_max_width+5
            last_data_frame_max_width = 0


class Sheets():
    def __init__(self, filename, key):
        self.filename = filename
        self.key = key
        self.data_worksheet = None
        self.url_worksheet = None

        self.getSheets(self.getCredentials())

    def getCredentials(self):     
        # sep = seperator
        _ = os.path.normpath(__file__).split(os.sep)
        _.insert(1, "/")

        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(os.path.join(os.path.join(*_[0:-1]), self.filename))
        return credentials.with_scopes( ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'])
    
    def getSheets(self, scoped_credentials):
        gc = gspread.Client(auth=scoped_credentials)
        gc.session = AuthorizedSession(scoped_credentials)
        spreadsheet_key = gc.open_by_key(self.key)
        # Get sheet with data import
        self.data_worksheet = spreadsheet_key.worksheet("Data")
        # Get list with url's
        self.url_worksheet = url_worksheet = spreadsheet_key.worksheet("Felix Copy")


# Get sheets
sheets = Sheets("credentials.json", "key_id")

# Start scraping
scraper = DataScraper(sheets)

scraper.StartScrape()
```

Comment: About `Since I am going to create a number of dataframes I know won't fit inside just a single google worksheet (because of the limitation of columns)`, can I ask you about the maximum number of columns you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike it's about 77000 columns or so

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, can I ask you about the number of rows? Because I thought that the limitation of cells in Google Spreadsheet might be required to be considered. https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603

Comment: @Tanaike it's maximum going to be 150 rows :)

Comment: Thank you for your additional information.